# can someone help me with path sum 2?

Tags: go, tree, binary-tree

need a little help with leetcode [path sum 2](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/) problem.

**Given the root of a binary tree and an integer targetSum, return all root-to-leaf paths where the sum of the node values in the path equals targetSum. Each path should be returned as a list of the node values, not node references.
A root-to-leaf path is a path starting from the root and ending at any leaf node. A leaf is a node with no children.**

```
              5
           /     \
         4        8
        /        /  \
      11        13    4
    /    \           /  \
   7      2         5    1
```

**Input:** root = `[5,4,8,11,null,13,4,7,2,null,null,5,1]`, targetSum = `22`

**Expected Output:** `[[5,4,11,2],[5,8,4,5]]`

**Explanation:** There are two paths whose sum equals targetSum:

5 + 4 + 11 + 2 = 22

5 + 8 + 4 + 5 = 22

**Actual Output:** `[[5,4,11,2],[5,8,4,1]]`

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * type TreeNode struct {
 *     Val int
 *     Left *TreeNode
 *     Right *TreeNode
 * }
 */
func pathSum(root *TreeNode, targetSum int) [][]int {
    result := [][]int{} 
    findPaths(root, targetSum, []int{}, &result)
    return result
}
func findPaths(root *TreeNode, sum int, path []int, result *[][]int) {
    if root == nil {
        return
    }
    
    path = append(path, root.Val)
    
    if root.Left == nil && root.Right == nil && root.Val == sum {
        fmt.Println("adding new path",path)
        *result = append(*result, path)
        return
    }
    findPaths(root.Left, sum-root.Val, path, result)
    findPaths(root.Right, sum-root.Val, path, result)
}
```

**StdOutput:**

```
adding new path [5 4 11 2]
adding new path [5 8 4 5]
```

Comment: you're passing `&result`, and you have `*result = append(*result, path)` , the recursive calls to `findPaths` all pass in the same pointer, so I don't see how you wouldn't expect the result to be modified... there's a reason why even the built-in `append` requires you to write `slice = append(slice, vallues...)` instead of `append(slice, values)`... Just reassign where needed, and pass by value where you want to avoid modification

Comment: i added stdOutput, can you help with current pointer approch.
and point where i am doing it wrong.